# How to populate a GridView drop-down list choices from SQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview, datagridview

Here is what I want my Grid View to do.

My SQL table Pharmacy_Data contains Item_Name and Item_Code

Populate the Item_Code from  Pharmacy_Data table. When I select the Item Name from the dropdown, It should fill the Item Code in the field.

[image: My Grid]

How do I go about this?

Comment: Are you able to bind the grid and fill the columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by adding a OnRowDataBound function to my GridView.

**OnRowDataBound="Grid_ItemList_RowDataBound"**

```
protected void Grid_ItemList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
    Connection con = new Connection();     
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

        //Find the DropDownList in the Row
        DropDownList ddlnames = (e.Row.FindControl("ddlnames") as DropDownList);
        ddlnames.DataSource = con.GetData("Select Item_Code,Item_Name from mytable");

        //TextValue Pairs of DropDown list
        ddlnames.DataTextField = "Item_Name";
        ddlnames.DataValueField = "Item_Code";
        ddlnames.DataBind();

        //Add Default Item in the DropDownList
        ddlnames.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select"));
        }        
    }
```

The above code pulls the ItemNames and their respective ItemCodes.

Now, to display the codes in the textbox on selection, I used the below event for the dropdown element

**OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlnames_OnChanged"**

```
protected void ddlnames_OnChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //Encapsulates the object back as a dropdown list
    DropDownList ddlnames = (DropDownList)sender;

    //Finds the control in the corresponding gridview row and edits the label
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddlnames.NamingContainer;
    TextBox IC = (TextBox)row.FindControl("itemCode");
    IC.Text = ddlnames.SelectedValue; 
    }
```

Well, that's what I had to do! :) 
Hope someone finds this useful someday.

Answer (score 0):

1.Set  Autopostback as true for Item name dropdownlist and write code for fetch data (Item code) inside the dropdownlist change event and fill Item code

Comment: My Grid view is not visible at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following [Link](http://www.tuicool.com/articles/RRBNVf).. This might help you in this. In the example in the link they use direct value to fill the dropdown using list instead use database for your case.